# JOIN by closer value to key

Tags: sql, join, hiveql

With the following sample data:

```
WITH values AS (
    SELECT
        1 AS shard,
        2008 AS year,
        1 AS value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        1 AS shard,
        20012 AS year,
        2 AS value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS shard,
        2011 AS year,
        3 AS value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS shard,
        1998 AS year,
        4 AS value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS shard,
        2001 AS year,
        5 AS value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        4 AS shard,
        1990 AS year,
        6 AS value
    ORDER BY year
),
data AS (
    SELECT
        1 AS id,
        1 AS shard,
        2010 AS year
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        1 AS id,
        2 AS shard,
        2000 AS year
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        1 AS id,
        3 AS shard,
        1990 AS year
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT
        2 AS id,
        1 AS shard,
        2010 AS year
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS id,
        2 AS shard,
        2000 AS year
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS id,
        3 AS shard,
        1990 AS year
)
```

I want to join my `data` collection with the values stored in `values` collection. Data has an `id` which differentiates each process, so I want to perform the JOIN for each id. Also, the JOIN has a double mapping key, which are the `shard` and `year` fields. I want to retreive, for each entry on my data, the value of the **CLOSER** year in my `values` collection which matches its `shard` attribute.

I have come up with the piece of code, but it is not working as expected as it doesn't consider the `values.shard` field, and it matches every year no matter the shard they are on.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        data.id,
        data.year,
        values.year AS closer_year,
        ABS(data.year - values.year) AS diff,
        values.value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY data.id, data.shard ORDER BY ABS(data.year - values.year)) AS rn 
    FROM data, values
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

For the sample data, the expected output should be:

```
id    year    closer_year    diff    value    rn
1     2010    2008           2       1        1
1     2000    2001           1       5        1
1     1990    null           null    null     1
2     2010    2008           2       1        1
2     2000    2001           1       5        1
2     1990    null           null    null     1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was missing just after posting the question. I will answer it in case anyone has a similar use case.

When rereading the text, I noticed that the "match the shard" property I was missing was indeed a left join, so rewriting the query like this solved the problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        data.id,
        data.year,
        values.year AS closer_year,
        ABS(data.year - values.year) AS diff,
        values.value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY data.id, data.shard ORDER BY ABS(data.year - values.year)) AS rn 
    FROM data
    LEFT JOIN values
    ON data.shard = values.shard
)
WHERE rn = 1
```